# Combating age discrimination as a 17 year old

Tags: salary, united-states, internship, discrimination

Recently I've been getting a serious jump on my professional career now having worked at a Fortune 50 company last summer and currently working for a company which IPO'd a month ago. I've recently understood a problem in my field that causes me to get offered significantly lower salaries just because of my age, not because of my skill level.

A way the companies I have/am working for try to maintain consistency is by determining salary primarily on location, age, and how far done I am with college. This makes it quite difficult for someone like me with extensive "informal" experience in the field to get a salary most appropriate given my skill set.

For the purposes of this question, assume that I have the skill set of a recent college graduate, the problem I've seen is that HR has difficultly quantifying technical skill set, and even if you have someone to vouch for you there is no clear process to evading the age restriction.

The sad part is that I am not just claiming that I have xyz skills, I have documented evidence in my resume. For example, given my field is information security, I have over thirteen documented vulnerabilities in my resume and six [CVE's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Vulnerabilities_and_Exposures) assigned to my name.

Although especially with this new job, I'm being placed in an exclusive team doing some seriously technical work, the same old "location, age, and college level" policy has been used to determine my salary. My issue is that my location, age, and college level do not accurately describe my skill set and value, and I feel like it ends up being a case of "reverse age discrimination".

Furthermore, compared to other engineering interns, I get paid substantially less (about 20%), although I might do more intensive tasks then them. They only get paid more because they are older and at a higher college level, when it comes to experience they only have one internship like I do.

My goal isn't to get paid at the same rate as a full-time hire, I only want to be paid at the same rate as other interns (regardless if they do less intensive work then me). How can I achieve at minimum the same rate as other interns?

Comment: Where are you? Basing you salary on "absolute Age" (not years worked for the company or years of experience) is illegal in many countries.

Comment: @nvoigt from my research age discrimination typically applies to those at a more senior age, but I live in Minnesota in the United States.

Comment: I'm not an authority of any sort on salary negotiating, but thought one thing might be worth mentioning. Companies often both pay and spend on new graduate hires significantly more than they are actually worth: it's an investment of sorts  on the assumption that the new grad will stick around for a few years and become more useful. Even if you are as skilled as a new grad, if you want to get the same bump, you'd need to convince them that you're not going to disappear before they get some value out of you.

Comment: In particular, you need to think how your interests in any additional education interact with their interests in keeping their employee long term. If you're as good as you think, there may even be opportunities for getting your education sponsored by the company in return for commitment for some number of years, and that may even be easier to clear with HR than the equivalent value salary boost. As in any negotiation, put yourself in their shoes to work out what they want, take some time to reflect on what you can offer, and decide what you want in return, in that order.

Comment: By the way there is no _reverse X discrimination_. There is only _X discrimination_.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am an intern and I am a college pre-freshman (I will be starting college this coming fall).

Comment: An intern is an intern. Interns always get lower pay. This is the reality. Ask for more pay when you are not an intern anymore.

Comment: @scaaahu when it's primary acquisition route for junior technical staff was internship to hire, my previous employer paid college senior level interns roughly the same hourly rate that it offered just graduated people (although the latters total package was much higher due to benefits).  I was told third hand that rates for underclassmen were significantly lower, leading down to near minimum wage for the occasional highschool intern we had in the summer.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere One of the other interns making 20% more then me have only one other internship experience (just like me). Furthermore, my assignment is much more low-level and intensive then the high level tasks assigned to other interns. I am comparing myself to other interns, specifically the one that makes 20% more than me is going into their senior year this fall. I do expect to be paid like a intern, that's exactly what I'm trying to do (I get paid 20% less then the other interns).

Comment: as an intern, you should be happy to be paid at all. I've had internships where the knowledge I gained was considered enough payment... And that was at an age significantly older than 17.

Comment: @jwenting fact is, engineering interns typically get paid. My question is less about complaining that I make too little and more about I'm making significantly less then *most* other interns.

Comment: I know that sometimes, your pay is tied to your age simply because there is a minimum that a company is required to pay you at a certain age. They have no incentive to pay you more unless you are applying for a full time role or specialist role. It sounds like the jobs you are applying for aren't actually dependent on technical skills, and more like the standard motions of Internships, graduate jobs and low level entry/junior jobs.

Comment: "Furthermore, my assignment is much more low-level and intensive then the high level tasks assigned to other interns." That probably explains the salary gap. Are you saying that you are assigned tasks whose level is too low compared to your skill set. Is there a possibility that you are underestimating the skills of the other interns? People learn a lot in college.

Comment: @Taladris I think he means "low-level programming" i.e. programming that is closer to hardware, not low-level as in simple.

Comment: @Taladris No, I mean low level in the sense that it's more complex closer to the operating system code, not that my work is easier. It's the opposite, my work is much more intensive and difficult.

Comment: *I am a college pre-freshman* Why would you expect to get paid the same as interns with more experience and education?

Comment: @EJoshuaS I'm happy you asked. The error in your question is "interns with more experience and education". The other interns may have more formal experience, but I'd argue that my position itself represents I have more technical experience in the industry. The other interns are writing very high level (technical term for less complex) Python applications whereas I am writing very low level Windows Kernel code in C. I think that pretty much sums up the situation.

Comment: @RobGates - Am a security engineer myself, so if you want to  jump in the Water Cooler - group chatroom, perhaps can help

Comment: @RobGates, I would not view high-level (as a measure of distance from the cpu) as tech-speak for less complex.  Turns out the kernel is much more predictable and reliable than end-users, so some times developing high-level code to interact with users is harder than kernel programming.  High-level has different style of complexity.

Answer (score 31):

I think you're overshooting here. It sounds like you're still in college, so I'll answer based on that assumption.

> I have over thirteen documented vulnerabilities in my resume and six CVE's assigned to my name.

This is of course fantastic. It certainly gives you a leg up compared to most other candidates your age.

But here's the thing - most companies don't offer a salary based on your absolute skillset, how many CVEs you have, etc. - they offer it based on *commercial experience in other similar roles*, and in the case of graduates (for better or worse), the *quality of your degree*. You don't yet have a degree, and you've worked in what sound like internship positions for a short length of time, which is great, but:

> Recently I've been getting a *serious jump* on my professional career now having worked at a Fortune 50 company last summer

...let's be realistic here, it's just an internship position or short-term employment contract. It might be a very good one, but it certainly doesn't equate to a "serious jump in your professional career". You can't realistically take a couple of good short-term work roles, a handful of CVE's to your name and expect to bypass the internship hiring process, jumping in at a graduate salary instead. It's vaguely possible that some *might* if you're really lucky, but in general companies just aren't set up that way.

However, the good news is that if you keep this performance up, and you prove that you have the other "soft skills" necessary to be a great asset to a team longer-term, you'll almost certainly rise high in the ranks very quickly at any decent company that recognises your talent. So shoot for the top-end roles *now* that give you the best experience, use that to build up a great CV, then look to shoot for the most competitive graduate roles out there.

Comment: Hey Berry, thanks for your answer, let me explain some things. Perhaps you misunderstood my main concern so I'll try to explain it better. The issue wasn't getting paid a graduate salary or skipping the internship process, rather I am significantly being paid less then my fellow interns just because of my age. I know well for one of them that works in my office, has one other internship that he got in his sophomore year of college, no other experience, but he makes significantly more than me. What my question is really asking is "How can I avoid being paid less just because of my age?".

Comment: And to regarding your comment about me calling my experience a "serious jump". The reason I said that was because my peers have not gotten internships, and even in my college it's expected you get an internship the summer after your second year. I got my first internship at 16, which is why I mentioned "serious jump". I don't hear everyday someone starting their career at their age.

Comment: @RobGates - you are getting paid less than other interns? I think you should highlight that in the question because at the moment it reads differently. Also... are you in the UK? The UK specifically has slightly odd minimum wage laws which are heavily affected by age.

Comment: @P.Hopkinson Updated my question, sorry for any confusion. No I live in the United States.

Answer (score 21):

I have been in something similar to your situation, though with less provenance, but I hadn't handled it well - dropped my college side job (where I handled 2x the average workload for 1/4 the average pay), which I later came to regret.

Now I have, among others, one exceptional 22 year old and a few average ~30 year old developers working for me. The 22 year old one is always coming up with new ideas, implementing them in record time, and criticizing bad ones harshly. He is firmly in the top 1% intellectually, doesn't think twice about pulling 14-hour workdays, documents his code religiously, and is generally awesome. This last bit is hard to quantify, but you know it when you see it.

Who would I bring with me long-term? No question there. But who do you think brings more value in business terms right now?

The truth is harsh. The 22 year old insists on doing things his way or no way, and that often costs a lot of time. He can't tell how long a project will take, so it's give or take 500%. He can't write formal reports about his own work. Can't write user-friendly documentation, needs a lot of back-and-forth to communicate anything to non-IT people. This means more time spent on micromanagement, more assistance for non-core work, and ultimately more time to deliver.

The average 30-somethings will take a job, give a time estimate (it will sting), and a week after the deadline you get the working software, the way you want it. Of their 15+ languages, 12+ are useless except for legacy code, but that means they can dig up and reverse legacy code. And they'll write plain, idiot-proof documentation. And they'll present it to the end user. And you can forget they are there, except hand them a new task every now and then.

The good thing is, this is very temporary. The awesome young developer will learn the language of the business, learn to compromise, slow down a little, but otherwise get much better in practical terms. And it isn't the age that matters, it's experience. Just plain years spent in the dreadful confines of a business, where one learns the double-speak, the idiocy of the users, the subtle ways to present their work in a good light.

You'll always earn less than your real worth at 17, but it's an opportunity to come out on the absolute top of your group. Get to the next level and top it out there. And the next. And the next. It will be notices, and the college years' work will count as real experience, putting you far ahead of your peers. I had such an opportunity and dropped it. Managed to recover... to probably halfway of where I could've been.

So to answer your direct question - you can't overcome it in the hiring interview. But you can by proving yourself at the job, and climbing higher from there. It doesn't take long. If you can get into FAANG companies, as an intern, do so, because the pay will be at the top of the industry once you graduate.

Don't think of your age as a weakness, think of the opportunities it opens for you to max out your standing in a few years. There will be plenty of time to make money, now you've got an opportunity to get the means to make money, like experience in top tech companies.

Comment: Hey Therac, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it seems like my age is both a blessing and a curse. My only comment is that I might have been asking the wrong question in the first place. My primary concern is that other interns (a few years ahead in college) make significantly more than me and that's what I'm trying to combat. All I want is to be paid fairly, any tips?

Comment: @RobGates Get into better companies that they can. Yes, you'll still probably be at the bottom there pay-wise, but it can still be better pay. And focus on maximizing your earnings in the future, rather than right now.

Comment: It does sound like your 22 guy has ADHD. I say so because I do myself.

Comment: @Therac Only issue with getting into a "better company" is that the company I'm at now is one of the best in the field. Sure I could probably try and get into a company like Google, but the only issue with that is that I wouldn't be doing the same low-level intensive work I love doing.

Answer (score 6):

**If you’re unhappy with your salary, you can certainly negotiate it.**

**However, I don’t think you’re experiencing age discrimination - rather you are being compensated for the skills you do have (technical) and should expect greater compensation as you demonstrate additional skills (behavioral and social).**

While you do have some technical swagger, you are certainly inexperienced. Working on a team, especially within large organizations like you describe, requires more than technical skills. Your education and work experience are indicators of these behavioral and social skills.

It’s reasonable to expect an individual who has shown steady progression through various roles or with greater education to be offered a greater salary than someone who lacks that experience or education.  Unfortunately, it takes time to complete a degree or get promoted a few times.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of several ways to adress your problem:

1. Look for companies where the owner/manager and the people responsible for hiring people have a technical background. People without a technical background tend to judge you based on the things they can judge and that is for example age, years worked in the industry, former jobs, ... And these are the things you don't want to be judged by I assume. Technical people think more time of their life about technical stuff and therefore tend to judge you more on your technical knowlede.
   In essence you have to choose who judges you.
2. Look at how you present yourself. It is a fact that ageism exists. But it is not as simple as looking at a number. Older workers tend to send other signals in their speach, bearing and cv. You could try to change the image you project to the world. If your birthday is the only outlier. It might get overlooked.
3. You could do contract work or try to build your own enterprise. There it is easier to hide your age.

If you are hellbent on staying in your current firm, it might be hard to negotiate a 20% rise just because the guy/girl next to you earns that kind of money for the same work. You might have more luck if you change to another position. A change like that, even if it is a lateral move, makes it easier to open negotiations since you negotiate acceptable pay for a specific position and not a raise for a position you are already filling for less money.

Comment: The funny part is that I have been tasked to do some pretty intensive work compared to the guy/girl next to me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for a new employer (while you're currently employed). During your interviews, if they seem interested, just tell them the truth.

"Because of my age, I do not have income parity with my peers. I find that completely unacceptable considering my experience and the amount of work I do."

Make sure that you first tell this to the hiring manager. The hiring manager will be your strongest advocate, not HR. And should the hiring manager really want to hire you, he'll know what he has to do to get you on board and to keep you around.

If you're afraid of losing your post-IPO stock options, negotiate that into the deal as well. Just tell them, if I leave before this date, I'll lose x worth of stock options.